# React useState hook doesn't take the right value after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

So, I'm building a stopwatch app on a dashboard and I'm implementing a feature where you can move the stopwatch(time) from one component to another. I pass a function as a prop to the stopwatch component from the parent which calls the API again with and triggers a re-render through state

[image of the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmlDY.png)

```js
const getTables = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetchTables();

      setTables(res.data.data.table);
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(error?.error.message);
    }
  };
```

I render the components like this

```js
{tables.map((e: Table) => {
          return (
            <Stopwatch
              key={e?.id}
              table={e}
              getTables={getTables}
              tables={tables}
            />
          );
        })}
```

All of this works fine and re-renders are happening.
The API works fine and it works as intended after refreshing. So here's my child component:

```js
const Stopwatch = ({ table, getTables, tables }: Props) => {
  const stoppedTime: Timestamp = {
    hours: table.active_stopwatch[0]?.hours,
    minutes: table.active_stopwatch[0]?.minutes,
    seconds: table.active_stopwatch[0]?.seconds,
  };
  const time: Timestamp =
    table.active_stopwatch[0]?.status == "paused"
      ? stoppedTime
      : seperateDate(
          table.active_stopwatch[0]?.updated_at || new Date(),
          stoppedTime
        );

  console.log(time, table.id, table.active_stopwatch); // time gives the correct hour/minute/second
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(time.seconds || 0); //these don't reflect the amount in 'time'
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(time.minutes || 0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(time.hours || 0);
...
```

Here's the function which handles the movement and api call

```js
  const handleMoveTable = async (id: number) => {
    const confirmed = window.confirm("Are you sure?");

    const payload = {
      table_id: id,
      hours: hours,
      minutes: minutes,
      seconds: seconds,
    };
    if (confirmed) {
      try {
        if (table.active_stopwatch[0] !== undefined) {
          await moveStopwatch(table.active_stopwatch[0].id, payload);
          getTables();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Stopwatch is not active");
        }
        toast.success("Success");
      } catch (error: any) {
        toast.error("There was an error moving the stopwatch");
      }
    }
  };
```

I tried using useEffect to set the values instead of settings them like shown in the code but same result. I'm directly displaying the values from the state, so I tried displaying them with the const time which works but has some bugs and is not the intended way. `window.reload` works but I don't want to reload the page. Is there something I'm missing or? Thanks in advance. If the description is vague I can always provide more information.

EDIT:
I added a console log to hopefully better illustrate the issue
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ6H8.png)

```js
  const time: Timestamp =
    table.active_stopwatch[0]?.status == "paused"
      ? stoppedTime
      : seperateDate(
          table.active_stopwatch[0]?.updated_at || new Date(),
          stoppedTime
        );

  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(time.seconds || 0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(time.minutes || 0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(time.hours || 0);
  console.log(
    "const time seconds = " + time.seconds,
    "stateSeconds = " + seconds,
    "table_id " + table.id
  );
```

As you can see from the image before MOVING seconds and time.seconds are the same, after moving one changes and the other doesn't. Really strange behavior.

Comment: elaborate the issue more.
what value does the useState get?

Comment: so `stopped time` gives me the time from the api in hours/minutes/seconds and I use that time to set the current hours/minutes/seconds as seen above in the `useState` hook. The `seperateDate()` function gives me the time it was last updated at(or created) and adds `stoppedTime` to it. So the issue is the state of 'seconds', 'minutes' and 'hours' doesn't re-render at all.

Comment: I tend to prefer using helpful async loading hooks like `useAsync()` from `react-use`, as the logic about loading data and handling errors can be very complex. https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md

Comment: You're passing an _initial value_ to `useState`. It's not going to update itself after the component initially mounts.

Comment: Even after a re-render triggers? So what do you suggest I do? I tried useEffect

Comment: I figured it out. I used useEffect with the `time.seconds` which worked. Thanks for your help.